# php curl login remote server

Tags: php, curl

I have tried all several methods and approaches to this problem and I'm stumped. I'm trying to log into www.senderscore.org with php. The site's log in is a post form to their index page. I need to do this because I need to lookup several IPs and log the information on a regular basis. I have tried posting with curl but I have had no luck. Every attempt just returns the page as if I did not attempt to log in. If anyone could help out with a code snippet I'd appreciate it very much.

edit: The latest attempt's block of code. this is the code inside a class function.

```
    $username= $this->username;
    $password= $this->password;

    $url = 'www.senderscore.org/index.php';

    $fields = array(
    'email'=>$username,
    'password'=>$password,
    'action'=>"localLogin",
    'Submit'=>"Sign in",
    'remember'=>'1'
    );

    $postvars='';
    $sep='';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
    {
        $postvars.= $sep.urlencode($key).'='.urlencode($value);
        $sep='&';
    }

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);          
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $data = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($data === false) {
        $data = curl_error($curl);
    }
    curl_close($curl);

    return $data;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the request being send from your browser?

Comment: Can you provide the CURL call you are using within php?

Comment: After posting the code I noticed the https:// was missing in the url. This problem was driving me nuts... ><

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this script, it should work with post; i haven't tested it:

```
$username = 'your_username';
$password = 'your_password';
$loginUrl = 'http://www.path-to-login.com/login/';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);

// ENABLE HTTP POST -  this is important in your case
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

//Set the post parameters - make sure to match username and password
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='.$username.'&pass='.$password);

//Handle cookies for the login
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

//Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER variable to 1 will force cURL
//not to print out the results of its query.
//Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
//from curl_exec() instead of the usual true/false.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute the request (the login)
$store = curl_exec($ch);

//the login is now done and you can continue to get the
//protected content.

//set the URL to the protected file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.site-logging-into.com/protected/file.zip');

//execute the request
$content = curl_exec($ch);

//save the data to disk
file_put_contents('~/file.zip', $content);
```